# AlarmManager fires every half hour instead of every hour

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager

I have a service, which should start every hour. I am testing with a Note 3.
As this is Android KitKat I changed the code to:

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
int valueOfHour = 3600000;
long time = System.currentTimeMillis()+ (valueOfHour - (System.currentTimeMillis() % valueOfHour))+ 300000;
Log.i("Calculated Time:", time + "  " + System.currentTimeMillis());
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT){
    am.cancel(pintent);
    am.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, pintent);
}
```

My problem is, that the Service is started at XX:05 (like I want it to) and also now and then at XX:34. I just don't know why. The calculated time is always right.

The code above is located in the onBind() Method.

Comment: You arent you using setexactrepeating for triggering alarm every one hour
alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
        1000 * 60 * 60, pintent);

Comment: I did this before and the same issue appeared. But why would the "setExact(...)" method be wrong anyway?